# Codeigniter Multiple Database connections

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm diving into multiple database usage. According to the codeigniter user guide. To connect to the additional databases use use the following

```
$db2 = $this->load->database('second');
```

then to interact use,

```
$db2->get('second_table');
```

I'm receiving a Fatal error call to a member function "where()" on a non-object.

for the following line

```
$db2->where('field1', $data['item']);
```

and also for

```
$db2->get('second_table');
```

Where am I going wrong with this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you sure $db2 is being set? The CI docs say you should set the second parameter to `true` to return the database object.  http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to return the database object, you need to pass a TRUE as second paramenter:

```
$db2 = $this->load->database('second', TRUE);
```

See the [manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html) on database class for more info.

Make also sure you've loaded the config for that database in application/config/database.php

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
//.........

$db['second']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
//..........
```

Comment: yea, left out the TRUE, duh :/ Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In config/database.php

/

```
* DB1 */
$active_group = "forum";
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['DB1']['hostname'] = "xxxxx";
$db['DB1']['username'] = "xxxxx";
$db['DB1']['password'] = "xxxxx";
$db['DB1']['database'] = "xxxxx";
and other configs....

/* DB2 */

$db['DB2']['hostname'] = "xxxxx";
$db['DB2']['username'] = "xxxxx";
$db['DB2']['password'] = "xxxxx";
$db['DB2']['database'] = "xxxxx";
$db['DB2']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['DB2']['dbprefix'] = "";
and so on...
```

you can use databases by

```
$this->DB1 = $this->CI->load->database('DB1', TRUE);
$this->DB2 = $this->CI->load->database('DB2', TRUE);
```

Comment: the other one is initialized in the model.. 

this one can be used in library, if you want to make one :)
jsut another way on how to use.. notice the $this->CI it means im getting the instance of CI so that I can use it as helper or library..